# How to remove undefined symbols from a .o file

Tags: c, shared-libraries, undefined-reference

I have to build a shared library using another static library. In that static library there are some function calls that are undefined in `nm output`. I want to remove those symbols, by getting the object file. I cannot delete whole object file, as some part of it is used. Is there any way of doing that.

**`nm output`**

```
request.o:
         U CLR_SECURE_MEM_START_ADDR   //want to remove
         U clrSMEMAlloc                //want to remove
         U clrSMEMCopy                 //want to remove
         U clrSMEMFree                 //want to remove
         U clrSMEMSet                  //want to remove
00000000 T copyBuffer
00000000 T copyParameter
00000000 T copyRequest
00000000 T freeParameter
00000000 T freeRequest
00000000 T getLinkFromRequest
         U _gp_disp
00000000 T initializeRequest
00000000 T initializeRequestQueue
         U isClrSMEMBuffer
00000000 T isParamInSharedMem
00000000 T isRequestInSharedMem
00000004 b RequestQueue
00000000 b RequestQueueHead
         U strlen
00000000 T verifyParameter             ////want to keep
00000000 T verifyParameterType
00000000 T verifyParameterTypes
00000000 T verifyRequestParameters
```

I don't have the source of this object file, so I don't know the prototype of the functions that I want to remove. If I had the source I could have written dummy definitions.
P.S 
**The library that I had was broken. Thats why I had undefined references.**

Comment: You don't need to know the prototypes of the dummy functions as they are never actually called.

Comment: Yes. correct. I used dummy functions and its working.

Comment: You just need to make sure that those dummy functions are actually never called by anyone.

Comment: Yes. I got this. Thats why in my answer i have written that its a workaround. In my case those functions are not called.

Answer (score 2):

According to Michael Walz's comment, I didn't needed to strip the .o file. I just had to create a file depend.c. Put a definition for those functions which were undefined. Then build it

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libdepend
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/depend.cpp

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DCLR_INTERAPTIV_I7 -DCLR_INTERAPTIV -v
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../RIP/include/ $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../hardware/libhardware/include/hardware $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../hardware/libhardware/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/src $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../RIP/inc

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES = libsmem.sastra

LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -v -L$(ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT)/system/lib -lsmem.$(TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM) -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../RIP/library -llibrary -llog -lcutils -lipc.$(TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM)

#this option will build executables instead of building library for android application.
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Take the .o of this file from out folder. 
Get all .os from the library.
now

```
 ar -x library.a   //get original object files
```

pack all .os in this library with depend.o by this command

```
 ar r library.a *.o  //put depend.o with other object files
```

Now build the shared library

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libRip
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/Rip_api.cpp src/Rip_crypto.cpp

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DCLR_INTERAPTIV_I7 -DCLR_INTERAPTIV -v

#only include corelockr and rip headers
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc/ $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/  $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../hardware/libhardware/include/hardware/

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/library -llibrary
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES = libsmem.sastra
#test seqr library
#LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -v -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/library -llibrary

#this option will build static library
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Now shared library should build without any issues.

*******Its a workaround, not a real solution.*******

Comment: Indeed you are eliminating the dependencies, but introducing false implementations for those, and you will normally that library broken. **DO ONLY WHEN YOU ABSOLUTELLY KNOW WHAT ARE YOU DOING**

Comment: Yes the library is broken after doing this. A word has been sent to the person who developed the library and asked for answer for the undefined references. Meanwhile these false implementations, explains the working of my test app which at the moment is more important.

Comment: Well, nothing said then.... but it's important to mark it with large letters, as nobody can assume this is a general procedure to support for hidden/unreachable libraries.

Comment: Edited the last comment to be more visible.